# Can you use WcfTestClient against WebApi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, wcftestclient

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx) suggests it was possible, or in the works, with some code that suggests it can be done, but I can't figure out what code needs to happen or the WcfTestClient's uri needs to be.

Here's the code from the article that makes me think I can do it:

```
// Metadata routes to support $metadata and code generation in the WCF Data Service client. 
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    ODataRouteNames.Metadata, 
    "$metadata", 
    new { Controller = "ODataMetadata", Action = "GetMetadata" } 
);
```

Is this feature implemented?

Comment: ASP.NET Web API can theoretically service *any* Http request, so I don't see any reason it couldn't be made to cooperate with the WcfTestClient. Is there an out-of-the-box way to get it to publish metadata compatible with the client generation employed by WcfTestClient? Not that I'm aware of. That article refers to a nuget package that provides such metadata specifically for an OData service (not a general Web API service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not work as you intend. WCF Test Client supports talking to **SOAP**-based services. OData is not supported in the current version.

Granted, as @Snixtor mentioned, you *could* create a SOAP service using ASP.NET Web API, including support for metadata (WSDL). But I really don't know of any good reason why anyone would want to do that.

Comment: +1 yeah, other than wcf test client, I don't know of a good reason to put soap on a shiny new webapi =)